# android annotations @background NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: java, android, android-annotations, networkonmainthread

Why I get this error? Shouldn't android annotations take care of threading? Any help will be appreciated :). Thank you

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        tradingHistory();

    }
    void myMethod() {
        tradingHistory();
    }
    @Background
    void tradingHistory (){
        Helper helper = new Helper();
        try {

            helper.TradeHistory tradeHistory = helper.getTradeHistory();
            System.out.println(tradeHistory.toString());
        } catch (Helper.HelperException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Please post the entire Java stack trace, rather than just the error message itself.

Comment: Which Activity do you use in Manifest?

Comment: Post log and android manifest file

Comment: I written both activities with underscore and without

Comment: Update you post. Add log from logcat and manifest

Comment: Konrad Krakowiak, thank you, my mistake was that I wrote both activities in manifest with "_" and without. Write as answer your comment

Comment: @sanevys Do you want to accept my solution?

Comment: 2minutes restriction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72256/discussion-between-konrad-krakowiak-and-sanevys).

Comment: ok :) thank you very much. I used android-annotation a long time ago - now I use ButtenKnife - there is no to many function as in Android-annotation but it isn't generate new Activity with _ Check it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably use wrong Activity in your Manifest - You should use `MainActivity_` instead of `MainActivity`

Answer (score 0):

if you're just doing some development you can turn it off using:

```
import android.os.StrictMode;

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
.permitAll().build(); 
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

but I'd recommend to dug into Android AsyncTask some more.

Comment: Please note the asker using AndroidAnnotations, and actually wants to replace AsyncTasks and such with annotations and code generation.