# Android - Checking server or url availability

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

Can someone help me with this code. 
I found so many results but nothing seems to work.
As android updates, some or most of its old code deprecates.
Maybe there someone who would know how.

> Example: **URL = "192.168.1.14"**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

> I am using **Android Studio** and I already put the above code in the **AndroidManifest.xml**
>
> My current Android build for my project is **Android 4.0**
>
> Forgot to mention that I used **WAMP Server** and **MySQL**, so the URL is from the server computer managing the website that I am attempting to access
>
> The code below uses android device ip address specified above. But keeps returning false.

```
public Boolean isConnectedToServer(String url) {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        HttpURLConnection con =  (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

        Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "NETWORK CONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "NETWORK ERROR CONNECTION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("APP", "exception", e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

> The code below same as before uses android device ip address specified above but loops the array of ip or in this case the entire network. But still keeps returning false.

```
public Boolean isConnectedToServer(String url) {
    int index = url.lastIndexOf(".");
    Boolean result = false;
    for(int octet = 2; octet <= 254; octet++) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://" + url.substring(0, index + 1) + "" + octet + "/").openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

            //Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "NETWORK CONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                result = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "NETWORK ERROR CONNECTION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("APP", "exception", e);
            result = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Any suggestion or fix to code?

> Exception returns: **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**

Comment: Check what error you're getting.  You probably need to get off the UI thread.

Comment: Did you specify any port number? If not, it's normally port 9000. Try 192.168.1.14:9000

Comment: How or where do I check the error to be prompted?

Comment: Look in your `catch` block.

Comment: Example: 'http://192.168.1.14:9000/Foldername' <- like this?

Comment: Check the logcat in android studio

Comment: i believe the code will not run and throw running network on UI thread exception.

Comment: Also, don't just toast a custom message. Actually print your exception from the catch and read it

Comment: It throws me a **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**

Comment: Either shift the code onto another thread or change the strictmode to enable network on the main ui thread.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862525/android-annotations-background-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: Do research on using AsyncTask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413625/android-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 0):

All network operations should be done using [asyntask](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html).since UI thread is shared by other resources in the phone you cannot run time dependent operation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try a research about AsynTask.

Comment: Please flag duplicate answers instead of answering them. This is a much repeated question on SO.